# Identity Server 4 External Provider Claims Extension

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, facebook-oauth

I've identity server 4 configurations in an ASP.NET Core app. Along with opened and profile scope I also want to get the birthday of the logged-in user as claims. I'm having no luck with the following configuration

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddFacebook(options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.AppId = "XXX";
                    options.AppSecret = "XXX";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
                    options.Fields.Add("birthday");
                })
```

Any idea why this is not working?

OIDC client request configuration

```
var config = {
    authority: "https://localhost:44330",
    client_id: "ff-client",
    redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope:"openid profile gateway identity",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5003/index.html",
    acr_values: "idp:Facebook",
    loadUserInfo: true,
};
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Do you meet any error? Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there have any error, and you could also check the http response whether it contains the birthday or not? Here is an article about [Retrieve User Details From Facebook In ASP.NET Core Applications](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-user-details-from-facebook-in-asp-net-core-applications/), hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check if user granted access. ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/common-scenarios/#how-to-get-an-access-token

> If you want to confirm that the User has granted your app the user_birthday permission, you can perform a GET operation on the /{user-id}/permissions edge. Assuming the User granted the permission, the API response would look like this:

Sample Response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission":"user_birthday",
      "status":"granted"
    }
  ]
}
```